# JsonSerializable with subclasses in dart

Tags: json, dart

I have an object hierarchy that I want to serialize to json using dart classes. Here's a sudo-code example:

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class Person {
  int age;
}

@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class Athlete extends Person {
  int speed;
}

@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class BaseballPlayer extends Athlete {
  int height;
}

@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class Building {
  List<Person> people = []; 

  Building(){
    people.add(Person());
    people.add(Athlete());
    people.add(BaseballPlayer());
  }
}
```

I can stream this out, but when I read it back, people has three "Person"s in it.. NOT a Person, Athlete and BaseballPlayer. it doesn't know how to load specific subclass types. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Morphy https://pub.dev/packages/morphy.

(I am the developer of the package)

It can serialise and deserialise json to and from subtypes.

```
test("1", () {
  var building = Building(people: [
    Person(age: 1),
    Athlete(age: 2, speed: 3),
    BaseballPlayer(age: 4, speed: 5, height: 6),
  ]);

  var json = building.toJson_2();
  var building2 = Building.fromJson(json);

  expect(building2, building);
});

@Morphy(generateJson: true, explicitSubTypes: [$Athlete, $BaseballPlayer])
abstract class $Person {
  int get age;
}

@Morphy(generateJson: true, explicitSubTypes: [$BaseballPlayer])
abstract class $Athlete implements $Person {
  int get speed;
}

@Morphy(generateJson: true)
abstract class $BaseballPlayer implements $Athlete {
  int get height;
}

@Morphy(generateJson: true)
abstract class $Building {
  List<$Person> get people;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77598300/1058292

Answer (score 0):

You could add corresponding enum type as runtimeType pointer

```dart
enum PlantType {plant, tomato, potato};

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class Plant {

  final PlantType classType;
  final String name;

  Plant({required this.name, required this.classType});

  factory Plant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    switch ($enumDecodeNullable(_$PlantTypeEnumMap, json['classType'])) {
      case PlantType.potato:
        return Potato.fromJson(json);
      case PlantType.tomato:
        return Tomato.fromJson(json);
      case PlantType.plant:
        return Plant.fromJson(json);
      default:
        throw 'Unimplemented type of Plant: ${json['classType']}';
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PlantToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class Potato extends Plant {

  final bool couldBeFried;

  Potato({required this.couldBeFried, required String name})
    : super(name: name, classType: PlantType.potato);

  /// check out if _$PotatoFromJson does super's fromJson()
  factory Potato.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PotatoFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    /** check out if _$PotatoToJson does super.toJson(), or apply it as ...super.toJson() */
    ..._$PotatoToJson(this),
  };
}

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class Tomato extends Plant {

  final bool isApplicableToSalad;

  Tomato({required this.isApplicableToSalad, required String name})
    : super(name: name, classType: PlantType.tomato);

  /// check out if _$TomatoFromJson does super's fromJson()
  factory Tomato.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TomatoFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    /** check out if _$TomatoToJson does super.toJson(), or apply it as ...super.toJson() */
    ..._$TomatoToJson(this),
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Deserialization:

1. You should define special factory method for the base class to deserialize sub-classes.
2. Additionally, it could include itself a property of runtime type string.
3. Corresponding to subclasses you should use their fromJson methods within base's factory method fromJson .

Serialization:

1. You should override toJson within subclass.
2. The toJson should addMapEntry to json map (directly). The Map Entry should contain runtime type string.

For an instance, code below:

```dart
const runtimeTypeSerialName = 'runtimeType';

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class Plant {

  final String name;

  Plant({this.name});

  factory Plant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final runType = json[runtimeTypeSerialName]! as String;
    switch (stringToRuntimeType(runType)) {
      case Potato:
        return Potato.fromJson(json);
      case Tomato:
        return Tomato.fromJson(json);
      default:
        throw 'Unimplemented type of Plant: $runType';
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PlantToJson(this);

  
  /// could be replaced with property of type "enum PlantType {plant, potato, tomato};"
  static String runtimeTypeToString<T extends Plant>() {
    switch(T) {
      case Potato:
        return 'Potato';
      case Tomato:
        return 'Tomato';
      default:
        throw 'Unimplemented type of Plant';
    }
  }

  /// could be replaced with property of type "enum PlantType {plant, potato, tomato};"
  static Type stringToRuntimeType(String runtimeType) {
    switch(runtimeType) {
      case 'Potato':
        return Potato;
      case 'Tomato':
        return Tomato;
      default:
        throw 'Unimplemented type of Plant: $runtimeType';
    }
  }
}

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class Potato extends Plant {

  final bool couldBeFried;

  Potato({required this.couldBeFried, required super.name});

  /// check out if _$PotatoFromJson does super's fromJson()
  factory Potato.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PotatoFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    /** check out if _$PotatoToJson does super.toJson(), or apply it as ...super.toJson() */
    ..._$PotatoToJson(this),
    ...{runtimeTypeSerialName: Plant.runtimeTypeToString<Potato>()},
  };
}

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class Tomato extends Plant {

  final bool isApplicableToSalad;

  Tomato({required this.isApplicableToSalad, required super.name});

  /// check out if _$TomatoFromJson does super's fromJson()
  factory Tomato.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TomatoFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    /** check out if _$TomatoToJson does super.toJson(), or apply it as ...super.toJson() */
    ..._$TomatoToJson(this),
    ...{runtimeTypeSerialName: Plant.runtimeTypeToString<Tomato>()},
  };
}
```

Comment: runtimeTypeToString, stringToRuntimeType could be replaced with: `enum PlantType {plant, tomato, potato}; class Plant { final PlantType type;  ...}; class Tomato { Tomato({required this.isApplicableToSalad, required String name}): super(name: name,, type: PlantType.tomato); ...};`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).