# how to use freezed on a class with custome function that inherits from a non-sealed class in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, sealed-class, freezed

I have just started learning freezed. I have a GameBase class below:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'game_base.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class GameBase {
  final int id;
  final String facilityName;
  final ActivityType activityType;
  final Level level;
  final DateTime startTime;
  final DateTime endTime;
  final int participantsNumber;
  final String admin;


  const GameBase(
      {required this.id,
      required this.level,
      required this.activityType,
      required this.admin,
      required this.startTime,
      required this.facilityName,
      required this.endTime,
      required this.participantsNumber});

  factory GameBase.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GameBaseFromJson(json);
}
```

Now i have another class called Game, which extends from GameBase. I'm trying to use freezed on this class. I also have a getter in this class. Game class is shown bellow:

```
part 'game.freezed.dart';
part 'game.g.dart';

@freezed
class Game extends GameBase with _$Game {
  Game._();

  factory Game({
    required List<UserBase> participants,
    required String? gameDescription,
    required String? activityGroundsName,
    required DateTime day,
    required double lat,
    required double lng,
    required int id,
    required Level level,
    required ActivityType activityType,
    required String admin,
    required DateTime startTime,
    required String facilityName,
    required DateTime endTime,
    required int participantsNumber,
  }) = _Game;

  factory Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$GameFromJson(json);

  get facilityActivityText {
    if (activityGroundsName == null) {
      return facilityName;
    } else {
      return facilityName + " - " + activityGroundsName!;
    }
  }
}
```

since I have a getter in this class, I must have a private custructor, as mentioned in freezed documentation. However, by doing so I get an error since I extend from GameBase and must call its costructor with its fields.

*Note: I know I can move one field up to GameBase and then have my getter over there without any issue, but since I've just started working with freezed I want to understand it better  and find out if there's any way to handle this?

Comment: did you get the solution sir?

Comment: @Jsoon not yet...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75506920/2787034

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem's same as this thread. Hope this thread will answer ur questions.

[Flutter/Dart: Subclass a freezed data class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285384/flutter-dart-subclass-a-freezed-data-class)