# Error on auto generated freezed code while extending another class. Is there a better way to do it?

Tags: flutter, freezed

```
@freezed
class ProductModel extends ProductEntity with _$ProductModel {
  // ignore: invalid_annotation_target
  @JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, explicitToJson: true)
  const factory ProductModel(
    int id,
    String productImage,
    String productPrice,
  ) = _ProductModel;

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductModelFromJson(json);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMr5R.png)

I tried changing the autogenerated file and error is gone but the whole point of auto generation does not fit in this situation if error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - to take out the methods in the extension.

Entity:

```
class UserEntity {
  final int id;
  final String email;
  final String? photoUrl;

  const UserEntity({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    this.photoUrl,
  });
}

extension UserEntityCopy on UserEntity {
  UserEntity copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? email,
    String? photoUrl,
  }) {
    return UserEntity(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      photoUrl: photoUrl ?? this.photoUrl,
    );
  }
}
```

Model:

```
@Freezed()
class UserModel extends UserEntity with _$UserModel {
  const factory UserModel({
    @JsonKey(name: 'id', required: true, disallowNullValue: true) required int id,
    required String email,
    String? photoUrl,
  }) = _UserModel;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserModelFromJson(json);
}
```